# signin fails in rspec, new version of ruby & capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After upgrading rails to v4, rspec and other gems, rspec failing to signin.

Regular signin works fine, just the rspec fails. I suspect that maybe it relates to cookies, due to `config.secret_token` and `config.secret_key_base`, currently only the first one is set, but I tried setting the other one as well.

In the spec after the `sign_in` I put `save_and_open_page` and I was not signed in on the opened page. However it does reach `redirect_back_or user`, so I know the process works ok and the problem is the actual signin/cookies. So I guess it has to be something with the cookie/remember_token, right?

---

**One of the spec's result error:**

```
  2) signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: scenario{ should have_link('Sign out', href:signout_path)}
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find link "Sign out" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**authentication spec:**

```
feature  "signin" do
  subject {page}

  before{ visit signin_path }

  describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

    before {sign_in user}

    scenario{ should have_link(user.name,  href:user_path(user))}
    scenario{ should have_link('Sign out', href:signout_path)}
  end
end
```

**untilities.rb:**

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email-signin",     with: user.email
  fill_in "Password-signin",  with: user.password
  click_button "signin-signin"
end
```

**_hearder.html:**

```
    <% if sign_in? %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to user_name_or_email(current_user), current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    <% else %>
      <%= form_for(:session, url: '/signinup', html: {class: "navbar-form pull-right"}) do |f| %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, id: "email", placeholder: "email", class: "span2"  %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, id: "Password", placeholder: "password", class: "span2" %>
        <%= f.submit "Sing-in/up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'          , via: [:get, :post]
```

**signin view code:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign in') %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :email, "Email"%>
      <%=  f.text_field :email, id: "Email-signin"  %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, id: "Password-signin" %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", id: "signin-signin", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    Not a member? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**signin controller code:**

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid password/email combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**signin helper code:**

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def sign_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end
```

**gem:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'mysql2'
#gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

# rails 4 new
gem 'protected_attributes'        # https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes
gem 'activeresource'             # https://github.com/rails/activeresource
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'   # https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching
gem 'activerecord-session_store'  # https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store
gem 'rails-observers'             # https://github.com/rails/rails-observers


# Dev and test gems
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.2'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '3.0.2'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
# group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
# end

#only test gems
group :test do
  #gem 'capybara', '2.0.2'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end
```

Comment: can you please post the rspec error, maybe everthing is working ok but you have an error in your spec, so the error log might help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the method name in `utilities.rb` to `sign_in_utl` (and change accordingly in the spec) and it fix the problem. The spec accessed the `sign_in` method in the session_helper instead the `sign_in` in the utilities.rb. In ruby 3 I didnt had that problem because the spec didnt see the helpers. If you know a way to fix it(tell the spec not to look on the helpers) - post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

in `untilities.rb`:

```
defdef sign_in(user) #this might be a problem (defdef)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email-signin",     with: user.email
  fill_in "Password-signin",  with: user.password
  click_button "signin-signin"
end
```

Comment: in the code its just `def sign_in(user)`, bad copy i guess.. edit Q